# How to calculate $P(A_1)$?

Tags: probability

Let the outcome of a random experiment is one of $A$, $B$ or $C$ events. Also Let $A$ (or $B$ or $C$) comprised of two events $A_1$ and $A_2$ (or $B_1$ and $B_2$ or $C_1$ and $C_2$, respectively.)

Let $W$ be another event and by total probability theorem,  we have
$$P(W) = P(A)P(W|A) + P(B)P(W|B) + P(C)P(W|C)\tag1 $$
and
$$ P(W|A) = P(W|A_1)P(A_1) + P(W|A_2)P(A_2)\tag2 $$

My question is if the probability of occurrence of $A$, $B$ and $C$ be equal and the probability of occurrence of $A_1$ and $A_2$ be equal too, then $P(A_1)$ in $(2)$ is 1/2 or 1/6 (i.e. 1/3 * 1/2)? why?

Thanks.

Comment: $P(W|A)=\frac{P(A_1)P(W|A_1)+P(A_2)P(W|A_2)}{P(A_1)+P(A_2)}$

Comment: Thank you Bey, I think my problem is solved by your comment. It is my fault!